# How can we delete multiple documents at once in elastic search that belongs to different indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch

I know we have `delete_by_query` API that can do this job, but I'm looking for a solution using bulk API. I tried to follow https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html but it's only working when we delete documents from one index. what about when we have more than one index that having comma(,) separated indexes like `index1,index2`

Comment: That way is not interesting for you?
PUT _bulk
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "index2", "_id" : "2" } }

Comment: I have couple of indexes, and not sure in which index that document will be exists, so I was looking for a solution like delete_by_query where we can pass multiple index and that is capable to find the document and delete it. So when I run below bulk query it does not work. {delete: { _index: 'index_1,index_2', _type: '_doc', _id: '123456' }}

Answer (score 1):

You can build the request like that:

```
PUT _bulk
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "products", "_id" : 1 } }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "idx_movies", "_id" : 1 } }
```

Delete in different indice the same _id.

The response will be (If find the doc, will be deleted else the response will be not found:

```
{
  "took" : 6,
  "errors" : false,
  "items" : [
    {
      "delete" : {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_version" : 2,
        "result" : "deleted",
        "_shards" : {
          "total" : 2,
          "successful" : 1,
          "failed" : 0
        },
        "_seq_no" : 7,
        "_primary_term" : 1,
        "status" : 200
      }
    },
    {
      "delete" : {
        "_index" : "idx_movies",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_version" : 1,
        "result" : "not_found",
        "_shards" : {
          "total" : 2,
          "successful" : 1,
          "failed" : 0
        },
        "_seq_no" : 1012,
        "_primary_term" : 2,
        "status" : 404
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) with different index name as shown below:

```json
POST _bulk
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "index2", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "index3", "_id" : "4" } }
```

Similar you can achive using Elastic Java or any other language client as well.